# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Re-Building classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, web

```
In Eclipse I wanted to delete set of class files and build once again.
```

I tried to delete a single file and tried to build once again after refresh the project
and workplace it doesn't work.

But if I do dummy edit in relevant .java file and build the whole project now It generates the deleted class file.

My problem is the same case with 1000 or n of file I can't do the same by Dummy Edit please let me know what to do.

problem  at the time of Building after deleting files from build folder is It tries to load the deleted files but those file are not available there.So in `Eclipse .log`   file it says Class file is not found.

Please help me to solve this problem .Thanks in Advance.

**Sample Log from Eclipse .log file :**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core 4 0 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE Publishing failed with multiple errors
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE Could not delete D:\WorkPlace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\amec\WEB-INF\lib\axis-ant.jar. May be locked by another process.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE Could not delete D:\WorkPlace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\amec\WEB-INF\lib\eclipselink.jar. May be locked by another process.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE Could not delete D:\WorkPlace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\amec\WEB-INF\lib\postgresql.jar. May be locked by another process.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE Could not delete D:\WorkPlace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\amec\WEB-INF\lib\sqljdbc4.jar. May be locked by another process.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 271 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE File not found: D:\WorkPlace\amec\build\classes\ecnet\rd\helper\AMECGRNHelper1.class.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 271 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE File not found: D:\WorkPlace\amec\build\classes\ecnet\rd\helper\AMECGRNHelper2$1.class.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 271 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
!MESSAGE File not found: D:\WorkPlace\amec\build\classes\ecnet\rd\helper\AMECGRNHelper2.class.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 271 2013-05-16 21:01:10.815
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Project -> clean`?

It should delete the generated classes and recompile everything from scratch.

Comment: I deleted files (*.class) manually in its real path and tried "clean" and "build" also not working.Thanks for reply.

Comment: It's a long shot, but make sure the folder itself isn't write protected or something like that.

Comment: of-course not because initially it generated and for single file it works if edit something.